# Как сделать пикселизацию изображения, используя модуль PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, pillow, pil

Чтобы из исходного изображения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получилось что-то вроде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в тему: [Genetic Programming: Evolution of Mona Lisa](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Pixelate Image With Pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30520666/4279)

Comment: у меня тот код в принятом ответе запустился, но показывал огромный экран с маленькими пикселями по центру внутри (мб я неправильно код собрал...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Реализация pixelate, где циклы на операции над срезами numpy массивов заменены для демонстрации:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Pixelate image.

Usage: pixelate [--npixels=<n>] <image>

Options:
  -h --help      Show this screen.
  --version      Show version.
  --npixels=<n>  Number of pixel in a row [default: 16].
"""
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np         # $ pip install numpy
from PIL import Image      # $ pip install pillow
from docopt import docopt  # $ pip install docopt

args = docopt(__doc__, version='0.1.0')
path = Path(args['<image>'])
im = Image.open(path).convert('RGB')
n = int(args['--npixels'])
pim = im.resize((n, im.height * n // im.width))  # keep aspect ratio
pim = pim.resize(im.size, Image.NEAREST)

# draw pixel margins
margin_color = (0, 0, 0)  # black
pixel_size = im.width // n
arr = np.asarray(pim).copy()
arr[::pixel_size, :] = margin_color
arr[:, ::pixel_size] = margin_color
Image.fromarray(arr).save(path.stem + f'-pixelated{n}.png')
```

Пример ([Lenna.png](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lenna.png)):

```
$ pixelate Lenna.png
```

Результат:

[image: Lenna pixelated 16]

Comment: Выглядит хорошо :)

Answer (score 4):

Ниже представлена функция [пикселизации](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/0f607f2b96b11acc74a678b1dd7d55d9aa3eef73/pil_example/pixelate_image):

```
from PIL import Image


def pixelate(image, pixel_size=9, draw_margin=True):
    margin_color = (0, 0, 0)

    image = image.resize((image.size[0] // pixel_size, image.size[1] // pixel_size), Image.NEAREST)
    image = image.resize((image.size[0] * pixel_size, image.size[1] * pixel_size), Image.NEAREST)
    pixel = image.load()

    # Draw black margin between pixels
    if draw_margin:
        for i in range(0, image.size[0], pixel_size):
            for j in range(0, image.size[1], pixel_size):
                for r in range(pixel_size):
                    pixel[i+r, j] = margin_color
                    pixel[i, j+r] = margin_color

    return image
```

Использование:

```
image = Image.open('input.jpg').convert('RGB')

image_pixelate = pixelate(image)
image_pixelate.save('output.jpg')

for size in (16, 32, 48):
    image_pixelate = pixelate(image, pixel_size=size)
    image_pixelate.save('image/output_{}.jpg'.format(size))
```

---

Результат:

**output.jpg**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**output_16.jpg**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**output_32.jpg**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**output_48.jpg**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно пару слов о сути решения упомянуть¶ Три вложенных цикла можно операциями над срезами попробовать заменить: `pixel[::pixel_size,:] = margin_color`; `pixel[:,::pixel_size] = margin_color`

Comment: На строке с `pixel[::pixel_size,:]` ругается `TypeError: an integer is required`